# How can I solve 'SplashActivity has leaked window DecorView that was originally added here' problem?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-view, android-lifecycle

I keep getting this error:

```
.view.SplashActivity has leaked window DecorView@537618d[] that was originally added here
```

The function that I use to show Dialog is this:

```
    private fun showDialog() {
        myDialog = Dialog(this)
        myDialog!!.window!!.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        myDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_my)
        myDialog!!.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        myDialog!!.setOnCancelListener {
            checkedmDialog = true
        }

        val tvMessage = myDialog!!.tv_message
        val btnOk = myDialog!!.btn_ok

        btnOk.setOnClickListener {
            checkedMyDialog = true
        }

        if (!showDialog!!.isShowing) {
            checkedMyDialog = false
            myDialog!!.show()
        }
    }
```

I did check with `null`, `this.isDestroyed` but didn't work. It seems like it go to the `next activity` *without* closing this `dialog properly`. I don't want my app to go to the next activity before checking all the dialogs. What should I do?

Comment: call dialog.dismiss() before exiting your Activity (in onPause() or onDestroy())?

Comment: replace !! with ? and check it

Comment: post the code for going to next activity !

Answer (score 0):

Please dismiss your dialog instance.

```
@Override public void onStop() { 
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to assign `null`?

Comment: when you dismiss your dialog , dialog instance stiil in memory so it reflect on some time when you again show you dialog, it will be throw Memory or window leaked exception.

Comment: Isn't there any way to dismiss and make it null at one function call?

Comment: no when your dialog instance have created , first dismiss your dialog.